# How to include javascript url dependencies in stackblitz?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, stackblitz

I'm trying to run something similar to this [example](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/blob/master/examples/local-projections/europe/index_austria.html) in stackblitz.

The code (not mine, but similar to what i'm trying to achieve) runs in [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/vfefa69x/) where you can include dependencies as url's from github but does not work when trying the same in stackblitz project.

I have tried to include dependencies in index.html like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/lib/proj4-compressed.js"></script>
<script src="https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/src/proj4leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrMufflon/Leaflet.Coordinates/master/dist/Leaflet.Coordinates-0.1.5.min.js"></script>
```

I have also tried some of dynamic loading code snippets but I always end up with

> L is not defined

Comment: any request errors, cors?

Comment: @madalinivascu problem is, I can't include those dependencies, here is the editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4nee5x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the script tags in the page `<head>` tag

```
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/lib/proj4-compressed.js"></script>
<script src="https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/src/proj4leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/MrMufflon/Leaflet.Coordinates/master/dist/Leaflet.Coordinates-0.1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-txe9h1?file=index.html)

Comment: now: Cannot read property 'CRS' of undefined. L.Proj.CRS is defined in https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/blob/master/src/proj4leaflet.js#L66

Comment: have you checked the demo?

Comment: i don't see that error in the stackbiz i provided

Comment: sorry, i just tried in internet explorer and there  it works, something with chrome then. thanks for help

Comment: i am using chrome and it works perfectly, you may have some chrome addons that interfere with the page

Comment: Opening stackblitz in Incognito mode worked for me.